# Ошибка при вызове masm64 функции из C

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, masm, x86-64

я пытаюсь скомпилировать masm64 функцию и вызвать её из C в visual studio 2019. При компиляции отдельно ассемблерного файла всё проходит удачно, однако при попытке подружить ассемблер с C возникают ошибки. Что они означают и как можно их исправить? (Я почти уверен, что проблема в настройках проекта)[image: Asm]

[image: C]

Comment: Вы бы все же использовали, как и положено, текст, а не копии экранов. Прочтите хотя бы вводную страницу сайта - вы же [даже этого не сделали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed)...

Answer (score 1):

Ну как бы вам сказать... Есть переводчик с английского, который знает только английский. Есть такой же француз. Вы даете каждому свой текст, они переводят, далее эти два текста складываются в один большой, все нормально.

Это аналог компиляторов языков ассемблера и С в объектный файл, который потом собирается в одну программу.

Но если вы дадите переводчику текст, в котором половина английская, половина французская?... Переводчик просто скажет - "а тут идет не пойми что, это я не знаю, ошибка перевода, это не английское слово, не английская грамматика".

Что вам и говорит компилятор.

Максимум, что вы можете использовать в исходном тексте С (кстати, почему в С? вы же компилируете С++) - это ассемблерные вставки (В VC++ - `__asm`), *со всеми их ограничениями*.

Comment: __asm не поддерживается в x64, поэтому это единственный нормальный способ связать masm и C(данный код в С и С++ не различается, по-моему, но дискусс не об этом)

Comment: @Den Цитирую свой ответ: "*ассемблерные вставки (В VC++ - `__asm`), **со всеми их ограничениями***" - в число ограничений, естественно, входит и это - невозможность использовать в 64-разрядном варианте.